# How do I handle embedded ComboBox action apart from Button Action?

Tags: button, javafx, javafx-2

I have a `Button` with an embedded `ComboBox` as a graphic node:

```
<Button alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" contentDisplay="RIGHT" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleQuickNote" text="QuickNote">
    <graphic>
        <ComboBox fx:id="cboQuickNoteList" prefWidth="5.0" />
    </graphic>
</Button>
```

The default behavior for the ComboBox seems to be to trigger the Button's onHandle method when an item is selected.

I tried to use a separate listener on the ComboBox, but that appears to be called AFTER the button function has been.

The Button Handler:

```
@FXML
private void handleQuickNote() {
   // Attempt to create new "QuickNote Transaction"
   Global.transactionListController.addTransaction("QuickNote");
}
```

The ComboBox listener:

```
// Add listener to the ComboBox to override the button function
   cboQuickNoteList.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue != null) {
            // Create new QuickNotes transaction
            QuickNoteController newQuickNoteTransaction = new QuickNoteController();
            newQuickNoteTransaction.setQuickNote(newValue);
        }
   });
```

How would I go about canceling the Button handler if an item is selected from the ComboBox?

Comment: Why do you have a ComboBox inside a Button?

Comment: It fits the design and functionality of my application. I could separate them but would prefer to keep the ComboBox within the button.

Comment: I am not sure what your functionality desires but I am sure there must be a better solution to what you currently have. AFAIT, in your current approach, there seems to be no way to know whether the user wants to click on the Button or the ComboBox. Moreover, since the buttons action handler is called first, things are even more difficult to filter.

Comment: The Button's `onAction` is actually called after the `ComboBox` selection has been made. I wasn't sure if there was some way to cancel the entire `onAction` method after the `ComboBox` listener has completed.  There certainly are other ways to approach the functionality I need, but I like the way the embedded ComboBox looks and, for my purposes, makes it clear to my users what its purpose would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comsume the `onAction` event at the `ComboBox`. This prevents the `Button` from receiving it too.

Inside the `initialize` method:

```
cboQuickNoteList.setOnAction(ActionEvent::consume);
```

Comment: This was perfect, @fabian. Thank you!